# Is it possible to scroll to an element using something similar in iOS like AndroidUIAutomator?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

As the title already suggests this is about scrolling in Appium in an native iOS application. In the Android app we use this:

```
MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()" +
     ".scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + myVariable +\""));");
```

This works well for our Android app and I was wondering if there is something similar that can be used for iOS. Is there maybe the option to use this method?

```
MobileBy.iOSClassChain()
```

I have no experience with it and I don't find anything in the documentation that tells me if there is a way to scroll to an element using this method with an option to enable or passing it through within the string that is passed to it. Is it just a faster way to locate elements instead of XPath or could it be used in a similar way as AndroidUIAutomator?

The above mentioned method for Android is much more reliable and faster than any touchAction which we used before and therefore I would like to switch to something similar in iOS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended best practice for performing controlled scrolling is using the Appium “mobile:scroll” script command. This command is performed using the executeScript() method.

```
RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.findElement(By.className("XCUIElementTypeTable"));
String elementID = element.getId();
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", elementID); // Only for ‘scroll in element’
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", scrollObject);
```

> “element”: The id of the element that you want to scroll – “element” must be scrollable.
>
> “direction”: “up”, “down”, “left, “right”.

For more information about scrolling, check [Scrolling in IOS](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=25199704)

Answer (score 0):

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 HashMap<String, String> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
 swipeObject.put("direction", "down"); //up for swipe
 swipeObject.put("startX", "90");
 swipeObject.put("startY", "400");
 swipeObject.put("endX", "90"); //"90");
 swipeObject.put("endY", "350"); //"200");
 swipeObject.put("duration", "2000");
 js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", swipeObject);
```

Comment: It would be nice to add a short explanation to the code